# Get string from a column based on value?

Tags: pandas

How am I able to get the string from a dataframe column based on a condition of a value?

```
     parameter    value
0    para_gas     54.53
1    para_iron    0.00
2    para_copper  23.98
3    para_silver  0.00
4    para_abc     2.32
```

I want to get all the parameter string name if it is more than 0. The final dataframe will look like

```
     parameter    value
0    para_gas     54.53
2    para_copper  23.98
4    para_abc     2.32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d = '''     parameter    value
0    para_gas     54.53
1    para_iron    0.00
2    para_copper  23.98
3    para_silver  0.00
4    para_abc     2.32'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

df = df.loc[df['value'] > 0.00]

print(df)

# output

     parameter  value
0     para_gas  54.53
2  para_copper  23.98
4     para_abc   2.32
```